# Python Request Error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am getting error (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)).I am reading reponse to dictionary below.When I am using try except block then sometimes its working fine but sometimes its getting this error.What is the reason for this error.Please suggest the root cause for this error.
Response code from response is always 200.

```
response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
try:
    data_dict = response.json()
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

the error:

```
Error:Python Request Error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: try to print the `response.text ` after except

Comment: What was the HTTP response code? You didn't check it